# Kohana before and __construct causes fatal errors

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I have controller which extends `Controller_Template`, and also i have quite few functions in it, so now i would like to add `before()` or `__construct`

But, if i do that i get error from `view` which says `Attempt to assign property of non-object` to make it more clear this is the line that gives me error:

```
$this->template->content = View::factory('pages/all_messages');
```

So my guess would be that View class have `before` function, but if that's the case isn't `before` or `after` functions useless for normal controllers?

Btw i'm using `3.2` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use before(). Make sure you call `parent::before()` at the top of it, and do your code after that. It's the reverse with `after(). Do your code first, then call`parent::after()`.

Comment: well that works perfectly, i just don't get it why don't they mention something like this in documentation

Comment: There is documentation on before() and when to use it. If you think more detail is needed, feel free to fork the documentation and contribute to make it better.